# Creating Object with JSON Post request

Tags: java, json, jersey, jax-rs

I'm creating a Rest API with JAX-RS (Jersey) and Jackson to handle the JSON objects. I want to let the user create a Brand object by seeing a post request with a son body that only some of the fields of the brand POJO is filled in.

This is my Brand entity:

```
@Data
@Entity
@NoArgsConstructor
public class Brand {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private long id;
    private String name;
    private int founded;
    private String founder;
    private String ceo;
    private String headQuarters;


    private Date created;
    private Date updated;


    @Transient
    private List<Link> links = new ArrayList<>();

    public Brand(String name){
        this.name = name;
    }

    public void addLink(String href, String rel, String action){
        Link link = new Link(href, rel, action);
        links.add(link);
    }

    @PrePersist
    protected void onCreate() {
        created = new Date();
    }

    @PreUpdate
    protected void onUpdate() {
        updated = new Date();
    }

}
```

If a user would send the following JSON body:

```
{
    name:"brand-name",
    founded:1974
}
```

I want a new Brand object with the only these two values, created and the id to be set, the rest should be null. Is there a way for me to create a new Object with these values when the JSON is unmarshalling? Or do I have to take it in as a JsonObject and then check which values are specified to then create a new object with them?

Answer (score 0):

In my experience, the easier way to do it is to use the JSON library from Google - **Gson** (https://github.com/google/gson), or any other JSON Library.

With the library, you can do this to get the data formatted in the way you like it

```
Brand aBrandObject = new Brand();
//set values
aBrandObject.setName("Google")
// ..........
String jsonData = new Gson().toJson(aBrandObject);
```

Comment: That's what I'm doing right now with Jackson. Turning objects to and from JSON is not a problem, what i*m wondering is if there is a way for me to create a new Object only using the son that is provided from the post request, or if I have to take that request and turn it into a new object manually.

Comment: How does your endpoint look like? I mean where the data is being posted to?

Comment: It's just a POST request to `/brands`

Answer (score 0):

I managed to find the answer to this question. I must have written something wrong when testing it, but jersey already does exactly what I'm asking for. By simply specifying what type of POJO you want the JSON to be turned into, the entity will be created and all none specified fields set to a default value. If you then add it to the database, and Id and a created timestamp are added. Great stuff!

Answer (score 0):

It depends on how the end point has been created. e.g, you can implement it this way

````
@Path("/brands")
@Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
@Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
public Response processData(Brand aBrand)
{
    // In this way, the same entity will be automatically created and you can use it
    System.out.println(aBrand.getName());

}



//or 

@POST
@Path("/brands")
@Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
public Response processData(InputStream inputStream) 
{
        //read json string data in inputStream
        BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(inputStream));
        StringBuilder out = new StringBuilder();
        String line;
        while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
            out.append(line);
        }

       String jsonStringData = out.toString();

}```
````